# Import multiple maven projects within single eclipse workspace

Tags: eclipse, maven, aem, m2eclipse

Is it possible to import multiple maven projects within a **single workspace**? Also is it possible to build directly from eclipse to an AEM author or publish or both instances?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can import multiple maven projects. You need to have [Eclipse Maven Plugin](http://www.eclipse.org/m2e/). Then following steps can be used to import projects to workspace

**File -> Import -> Maven -> Existing Maven Projects -> Browse Root Directory**

You can deploy the Project to AEM using maven build profiles. In `pom.xml` you can [add build profiles](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/develop/dev-tools/ht-projects-maven.html#How-To%20Work%20with%20Deployment%20Profiles), and using maven you can specify particular profile while installing.

Comment: So sandeep - does that imply i can import two different maven based AEM projects into a single Eclipse workspace ?

Comment: Yes, import picks up projects based on `pom.xml`. Projects can be multi-module or simple.

Comment: Could we also import two multimodule projects within the same single eclipse workspace?

Comment: Yes you can, your multi-module projects should be under directory you are choosing while importing the projects. if Directory myDir has multi-module project foo, bar. Select path till directory myDir while importing